# Find particular string and value for it in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am searching for a particular name in column 'names' and its value.
for e.g, I want to search for string 'pqr' in column 'names' and get its values from 'Total' column, which is 304
so the final output is **304**.

**Input:**

```
    names       Total
0    abc          186
1    xyz          545
2    pqr          304
3    lmn          405
4    def            0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with mask and then select for first match value converted values to array and select first one:

```
df.loc[df['names'] == 'pqr', 'Total'].to_numpy()[0]

#or select first match value by position
df.loc[df['names'] == 'pqr', 'Total'].iat[0]
```

Or for more general solution working also if no match use:

```
next(iter(df.loc[df['names'] == 'pqr', 'Total']), 'no match')
```

Comment: can I know why call `to_numpy()` here?

Comment: @billz - it is solution for get first value, because get one element `Series` from `df.loc[df['names'] == 'pqr', 'Total']`

Answer (score 0):

This code fits your example:

```
df[df['names'] == 'pqr']['Total']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df['names']=='pqr','Total']
2    304
Name: Total, dtype: int64
```